# Conda doesn't recognize -add channels command

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am new to Anaconda notebook hosted on the Anaconda Cloud.
I have set up the new environment (python_programming) and have changed from base to the new environment. But when I enter the -add channels command, I get an error response from conda that it does not recognize the arguments. Screenshot attached.
How to fix this?
Thank you.

Entered conda -add channels command but it was not recognized by the Anaconda Terminal.[image]

Comment: Close voting. This is a typo: `-add` should be `--add` (two hyphens).

Answer (score 0):

Instead use

```
conda config -add channels conda-forge
```

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Example:
[example_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDyUD.png)

But using `--append` is better than `--add`, otherwise the `defaults` channel get lesser priority than the added one, `conda-forge` in this case.

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

Exmaple:
[example_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SASee.png)

Comment: I agree that the `--append` and `--prepend` arguments should be preferred to `--add` when order matters. However, I don't think you should weigh in on *which* of those should be preferred without explaining why (i.e., why would giving `defaults` lower priority be a bad thing?).